# Outlook 2013: Multiple accounts, sign only mails from one account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, certificate, smime

I have two email accounts (Exchange) configured in Outlook. For one I have a S/MIME certificate configured which always signs the mails I send from this account.

Problem now is that Outlook also attempts to sign the mails I send from the other account. Obviously I always get an error message

> Invalid certificate: Outlook cannot sign or encrypt this message because there are no certifcates which can be used to send emails from this adress "abc@example.com"

So, is there any way to configure Outlook to sign only emails from one account by default? Someone had a solution for multiple accounts and multiple certificates [here](https://superuser.com/questions/626538/outlook-2013-multiple-email-accounts-and-encrypted-email-only-last-s-mime-sett), but I dont have a certificate for the second account.

Thanks!

Comment: Which account have you selected as the default address?

Comment: The one for which I have the certificate.

Comment: Which order did you add the accounts to Outlook?  In what order do they appear in the list of email accounts?  Is the default account the first account?

Comment: Yes it is. The default one was there first.

Comment: I asked three questions but recieved a single answer.

Comment: Well, the answer was always the same...

I added the default account first. Then I added the second account and later I configured my SMIME certificate which is valid for the first/default account. What are you missing?

Comment: A response exactly like that?

Comment: I know it has been a while but did you fin a solution for this problem?